# Dealing with VarVector<Single> Feature column in ML.NET

Tags: c#, ml.net

I have a tricky model I'm trying to normalize for binary classification. Here's an example of the model structure. I renamed a few things just to simplify.

```
    public class Review
    {
        public bool Label { get; set; }
        
        public ReviewItem ReviewItem { get; set; }
        
        public List<OtherItem> OtherItems { get; set; }
    }

    public class ReviewItem
    {
        public string SomeText { get; set; }

        public float SomeNumber { get; set; }

        public bool SomeBool { get; set; }
    }

    public class OtherItem
    {
        public string SomeDifferentText { get; set; }

        public float SomeDifferentNumber { get; set; }

        public bool SomeDifferentBool { get; set; }
    }
```

There can be any number of `OtherItem` in the List. This is what I tried to flatten the model a bit.

```
    public class ReviewMlModel
    {
        public bool Label { get; set; }
        
        public string ReviewItem_SomeText { get; set; }

        public float ReviewItem_SomeNumber { get; set; }

        public bool ReviewItem_SomeBool { get; set; }
        
        public string[] OtherItem_SomeDifferentText { get; set; }

        public float[] OtherItem_SomeDifferentNumber { get; set; }

        public bool[] OtherItem_SomeDifferentBool { get; set; }
    }
```

From there I tried this to normalize it:

```
var data = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(allReviews);

var dataPrepEstimator = mlContext.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText("ReviewItem_SomeText")
   .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText("OtherItem_SomeDifferentText"))
   .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.ConvertType("ReviewItem_SomeBool"))
   .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.ConvertType("OtherItem_SomeDifferentBool"))
   .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", 
           "ReviewItem_SomeText", "OtherItem_SomeDifferentText", "ReviewItem_SomeBool", 
           "OtherItem_SomeDifferentBool", "ReviewItem_SomeNumber", "OtherItem_SomeDifferentNumber"));
var transformedData = dataPrepEstimator.Fit(data).Transform(data);

var model = mlContext.BinaryClassification.Trainers.AveragedPerceptron()
    .Fit(transformedData);
```

This gives me the exception on the line where I try to create the model:

```
Schema mismatch for feature column 'Features': expected Vector<Single>, got VarVector<Single> (Parameter 'inputSchema')
```

I'm guessing this is due to the fact these arrays all have variable lengths, but I don't see a way to transform the `VarVector`. Do I need to go make the original `allReviews` enumerable have the same length array for every array? Or am I way off track with how I flattened the original model?

Comment: I tried copying all of the arrays into an array of a fixed size before loading the enumerable and got the exact same exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was a combination of changing the arrays to all have the same size, as well as adding `[VectorType(size)]` attribute to all the array properties.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Could you add a bit more code to the solution please?